# Stopping sewer smell

Tags: drain, pipe, sewer

I have a sewer near the house where two sewer pipes meet. The problem is that it's been built badly and a lot of sewage remains there instead of going in the 3rd pipe. How could I make it go through the pipe?

[image]

Comment: Is that picture looking straight down into some kind is sewer pit?

Comment: No, it's horizontal. The pipe on the bottom goes to the town sewer

Comment: Being from the US, this seems very odd...  Why aren't those pipes just connected?  Is there some air-gap requirement?

Comment: I had them connected, but there was smell coming from the street sewer, so I placed this valve to stop the smell from the street, but I don't have enough space to connect them anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The outlet pipe needs to be the lowest point so anything that arrives goes down the pipe, also it all needs to be smooth feeding the outlet.

So, I suggest that needs re-building.

Comment: It is like 20-30cm lower than the other pipes and most of it goes in it, but some go around it.

Comment: None should go around it - that's the point of what I said.